# how to convert text file to json string (replace newlines with "\n")

Tags: text-processing, json

we have the following file :

```
more value.js

"\n#\n#\n# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one\n# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file\n# distributed with t                    his work for additional information\n# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file\n# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the\n# \                    "License\"); you may not use this file except in compliance\n# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at\n#\n#   http://www.apache.org/lic                    enses/LICENSE-2.0\n#\n# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,\n# software distributed under the License is distributed on an\n# \"AS I                    S\" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY\n# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the\n# specific language governing permissions                     and limitations\n# under the License.\n#\n#\n#\nkafka.logs.dir=logs\n\nlog4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout\n\nlog4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppen                    der\nlog4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout\nlog4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n\n\nlog4j.appender.kafkaA                    ppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender\nlog4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH\nlog4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.log                    s.dir}/server.log\nlog4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout\nlog4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c                    )%n\n\nlog4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender\nlog4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH\nlog4j                    .appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log\nlog4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout\nlog4j.appe                    nder.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n\n\nlog4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender\nlog4j.appe                    nder.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH\nlog4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-request.log\nlog4j.appender.requestAppender.                    layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout\nlog4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n\n\nlog4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apac                    he.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender\nlog4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH\nlog4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/log-c                    leaner.log\nlog4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout\nlog4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n                    \n\nlog4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender\nlog4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH\nlog4j.appe                    nder.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log\nlog4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout\nlog4j.appender.cont                    rollerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n\n\n# Turn on all our debugging info\n#log4j.logger.kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=DEBUG                    , kafkaAppender\n#log4j.logger.kafka.client.ClientUtils=DEBUG, kafkaAppender\n#log4j.logger.kafka.perf=DEBUG, kafkaAppender\n#log4j.logger.kafka.perf.Produ                    cerPerformance$ProducerThread=DEBUG, kafkaAppender\n#log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=DEBUG\nlog4j.logger.kafka=INFO, kafkaAppender\nlog4j.logger.                    kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender\nlog4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false\n\n#log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, r                    equestAppender\n#log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender\n#log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false\nlog4j.logger.kafka.request.log                    ger=WARN, requestAppender\nlog4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false\n\nlog4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE, controllerAppender\nlog4j.additivity.kafka.c                    ontroller=false\n\nlog4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO, cleanerAppender\nlog4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false\n\nlog4j.logger.state.change.logger                    =TRACE, stateChangeAppender\nlog4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false"
```

by the following trick , we can convert the "\n" to new lines and create the **file.txt**

```
var=` cat value.js `
echo -e "$var" | tee -a /tmp/file.txt

"
#
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# \"License\"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# \"AS IS\" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#
#
#
kafka.logs.dir=logs

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/log-cleaner.log
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

# Turn on all our debugging info
#log4j.logger.kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=DEBUG, kafkaAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.client.ClientUtils=DEBUG, kafkaAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.perf=DEBUG, kafkaAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.perf.ProducerPerformance$ProducerThread=DEBUG, kafkaAppender
#log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=DEBUG
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO, kafkaAppender
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false

#log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=TRACE, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false"
```

my question is how to convert back the **file.txt** to the previous format as **value.js** file ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of `echo`, you could use the `jq` JSON parsing tool:

```
jq -r . < file.js > file.txt
```

It would also have the advantage of removing the enclosing `"`, and turning the `\"` into `"`.

To convert back to a JSON string:

```
jq -Rs . < file.txt > newfile.js
```

For the more generic question about converting newlines to `\n`, you can use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/'
```

The difference with <strike>`sed 's/\n/\\n/'`</strike> which wouldn't work is that `perl` includes the trailing newline in the record that `s` operates on, but not `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672680/replace-newlines-with-literal-n) in the stackoverflow.

Here you would use:

```
sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r{0,1}\n/\\n/g' file.txt > value.js
```

Comment: While you're at using GNU extensions and loading the whole file in memory, you might as well make it `sed -zE 's/\r?\n/\\n/g'`